# AWS Device Farm "No suites found to execute" after running Calabash test

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, automation, calabash

I have tried submitting the tests in a few different ways but keep receiving this error. Anyone have any ideas?  Below is the format that I have submitted my tests in.

```
mytests.zip
  -features
     - step_definitions
        -  steps.rb
        -  moresteps.rb
     - support
        - app_installation_hooks.rb
        - app_life_cycle_hooks.rb
        - env.rb
        - hooks.rb
     - firstfeature.feature
     - secondfeature.feature
     - thirdfeature.feature
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the issue.  I removed the profile name from the run and the tests ran perfectly.

Comment: what do you mean by "profile name from the run" ?

Answer (score 1):

Would you be able to answer a few questions?

- Are you able to run these tests on a physical Device?
- Are you using Calabash to run tests on iOS or Android?
- Are you using the same version of Calabash that Device Farm is running?

Android: 0.7.2 [1]

iOS: 0.20.3 [2]

- Are you utilizing profiles with this test?

If you are make sure you are including the config directory with the cucumber.yml file inside of the zip uploaded to device farm. Hence your test package would then look like:

```
mytests.zip
  -config
     -cucumber.yml
  -features
     - step_definitions
        -  steps.rb
        -  moresteps.rb
     - support
        - app_installation_hooks.rb
        - app_life_cycle_hooks.rb
        - env.rb
        - hooks.rb
     - firstfeature.feature
     - secondfeature.feature
     - thirdfeature.feature
```

Look forward to your response

Best Regards 
  James

[1] http://docs.aws.amazon.com/devicefarm/latest/developerguide/test-types-android-calabash.html#test-types-android-calabash-version-information

[2] http://docs.aws.amazon.com/devicefarm/latest/developerguide/test-types-ios-calabash.html#test-types-ios-calabash-version-information